# Laravel 8 - Can't set cookies in middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm building a shopping cart SPA using Laravel and Vue.

Vue communicates with Laravel via the API, which is not a stateless as I'm using Sanctum for a cookie based session authentication services.

For guest users I want to store the cart info in a cookie. So I'm trying to set a cookie via a middleware I created with the following handle() method:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!$request->cookie('cart_id')){
        $cart_id = "some value";
        return $next($request)->cookie(cookie()->forever('cart_id', $cart_id));
    }  
    return $next($request);
}
```

I added this middleware to both 'api' and 'web' groups, but it doesn't seem to add the cookie no matter how many page requests I make.

Would appreciate some help with this Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Did you verify that the program is making it into this middleware?

Comment: @Andrew thanks for replying. I was trying to test the middleware. When I open it in the browser it works fine (the cookie gets set). It might be that in testing, one can only set a cookie using the withCookie() method?? How would it be possible to test middleware in such case?

Comment: I would place a ```dd()``` in the middleware, potentially multiple. Something like ```dd("Request Cookie: ". $request->cookie('cart_id'))``` before the ```return $next($request);``` and another one inside the ```if``` statement.

Comment: the dd() before the return $next($request) never gets called. That means that cookie never really gets set

Comment: Are you talking about a `dd()` inside the `if()` statement? If you place a `dd()` outside of the `if()` will it get called?

Comment: outside the if() statement. It never gets past it

Comment: I want to know if the program ever makes it inside the middleware to begin with. If you place a `dd($request->cookie('cart_id'))` at the beginning of the method, what happens? Does the dd get hit? Is there a value for the `cart_id`?